# Why flex elements are not going to next line when flex-basis is provided?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to add width to the flex elements. I have provided the `flex-basis:20%`. How can I get the 6th and 7th element in next row/line?

Adding the scratch pad link below: [scratchpad.io](http://scratchpad.io/zany-store-3715)

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.children {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="children">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    5
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="children">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    7
  </div>


</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Relevant resource to kukkuz answer: [flexbox on SO documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/445/flexible-box-layout-flexbox#t=2016121510252967663&a=remarks-resources-1)

Answer (score 17):

Use the *wrapping* property - `flex-wrap: wrap` on your `flexbox`.

Even the horizontal margins affect wrapping - so set `margin: 0` to `body` to reset the default browser margins and apply `box-sizing: border-box` to take care of the borders too.

See demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.children {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="children">1</div>
  <div class="children">2</div>
  <div class="children">3</div>
  <div class="children">4</div>
  <div class="children">5</div>
  <div class="children">6</div>
  <div class="children">7</div>
</div>
```